# Pass complete model from child to parent

Tags: angular

I created a Angular2 component with a checkbox inside it and I'm calling it from parent:

```
// My model
export class Term {
   id: number;
   checkbox: boolean;
   name: string;
   ...
}

export class TermComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  term: Term; // my model

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getTerm(); // a http call that fill the term variable
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
     this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
     this.onBlur = fn;
  }

  writeValue(obj: Term): void {
     this.term = obj;
  }

  onChanged($event) {
     this.term.checkbox= $event && $event.target && $event.target.checked;
     this.onChange(this.term.checkbox);
  }
}

  ...
```

On parent. I'm adding TermComponent like this:

```
<term
    [(ngModel)]="term"
    name="term">
</term>
```

But in the app, when I check the checkbox, my parent term returns true/false. I want it to return the complete model. How can I do that?

Comment: This may help, you need the triad mentioned here. https://dev.to/jwp/ngmodel-internals-2m9f